# Why can't the king castle in this position?

Tags: rules, castling

In a [video I'm watching](https://www.chesscademy.com/videos/the-king-in-the-center) (requires register), it has this setup.

```
[FEN "r3k2r/pp1qn1pp/2p2p2/8/3P4/5N2/PP2QPPP/2R1R1K1 b kq - 0 1"]
[startflipped ""]
```

The instructor says:

> The king cannot escape, he cannot castle kingside or queenside,
> because of the white's pressure on e7 [...]. Black wants to escape
> this pressure by castling by hand.

I don't understand why can't black castle. It won't castle [from, through, or into check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling#Requirements). Why is it?

Comment: Black certainly can castle for both sides, but if he does... you know that `Qxe7 Qxe7` followed by `Rxe7` winning the knight as well. White gaining material advantage afterwards.

Comment: He just means you better not castle.

Comment: In other words, the king _should_ not escape or castle to either side, because it would mean giving a queen and knight (and if he castles queenside, a pawn, for after `Qxe7 Qxe7` `Rxe7` Black can't defend both`... Rxb7` and `... Rxg7`) for a queen.

Comment: I remember this game as one played by Steinitz in the Hastings 1895 tournament.. definitely not someone who should be annotated as NN. White later sacs a pawn by playing d5 so he can play Nd4 Nf5 so that he can put further pressure on the kingside.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Executive summary:**

Black actually can castle, but if he does castle he will lose the knight and the game (due to material loss).

**Detailed answer:**

Black and White have equal material.

- The black knight is protected by two pieces: the king and the queen.
- The black knight is attacked  by two pieces: the queen and rook.

If the king castles, the knight will be protected only by the queen, and White will be able to win the knight which will lead to a big material advantage: a knight, which is worth about 3 points.

"Castle by hand" (meaning moving the king and the rook over several turns until they reach a castle position) will allow Black to keep protecting the knight. (E.g. By moving the king to F7 to protect the knight, followed by a rook to E8, etc.)

Comment: Ok, so it wouldn't be _illegal_, just a bad idea because white would lose a knight, correct?

Comment: @nprensen - correct - this is my understanding.

Comment: @nprensen - did I answer your question?

Comment: @nprensen Except if the king has been moved earlier in the game, then you're not allowed to castle. Or if a rook has been moved earlier, then you cannot castle with that rook. But that's probably not the case in this game.

Comment: @Paul yes you can, if you move it back to its original position.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling#Requirements): "Neither the king nor the chosen rook has previously moved."

Comment: @Paul I'm pretty sure that I was taught what I say back in the 80'es but that was probably tightened later to ensure clarity.  I cannot find anything to back this up, so I'm probably just plainly wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one possibility when castling would be illegal - if king has moved earlier in the game - then the move would be illegal.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! While this is correct in general, this does not apply to the question at hand.

Comment: This is the famous game [Wilhelm Steinitz vs Curt von Bardeleben, 1895](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1132699). Black hasn't moved the king before the position shown in the game.

Comment: You cannot move your king over a check to castle either.

Comment: @johnny But there is no check in this position.